# asp.net mvc partials do they know if the are run stand alone or as part of a page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Does anyone know, if a partial view (`PartialViewResult`) in an ascx file - knows if it is running stand alone - called directly from the browser or as part of a page.

I would like to treat these cases differently.

**Edit:

Case 1:** In the page case it could be that a page has a few partials that are loaded using ajax while the page is being built. The partials might be called again using ajax according to the users actions. In this case I consider them as controls on a page.

**Case 2:**In the stand alone case the partial could be called as part of a test directly from the browser. In this case you only see the partial part in the browser.

**Case 3:**In the third case the partial could be called as part of an iframe within a google chrome extension (for example). In this case you can see the partial in a page that might not have been built in your web application.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance of for those whom it concerns - happy new year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could distinguish between normal requests and ajax requests (`Request.IsAjaxRequest()`) and child actions (`ControllerContext.IsChildAction` - rendered with `Html.Action`).

As an alternative the controller action returning the partial view could set some model property indicating that the partial was rendered via this action instead of being directly included in a view with `Html.RenderPartial` for example.

Comment: @Darin - first of all thanks. I will update my question to clarify what I am looking for as I am not sure that I understand you completely. I will need to read a bit more about each of the alternatives you presented.

Comment: @Julian, here's an example `return PartialView("foo.ascx", new MyViewModel { IsPartialRendered = true });` and then inside the partial you could test the value of `Model.IsPartialRendered`.

Comment: @Darin - can the controller distinguish between an ajax call that is performed from within a page on site, or a direct call from the browsers navigation input?

Comment: @Julian, yes by using `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`.

Comment: @Darin - thanks again, is this Request.IsAjaxRequest() information still available in the partial or do I need to pass it down from the controller as a parameter. (Is doing so a good practice?) Please don't kick me for this one- Can an ajax call be initiated from a different site?

Comment: @Julian, yes it is available but I would probably add it as part of a view model property because all that a view should work with is a view model. Views should only use the information passed by the controller and not pull data themselves. As far as your second question about AJAX call from different site I don't understand what do you mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Darin Site A is my web application that works with pages and partials. Site B is someone else's site. Can site B from within its application call a partial using Ajax and get the partial back to his application?

Comment: @Julian, due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) AJAX requests cannot be sent across different domains. You could use [JSONP](http://insideria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html) to simulate cross domain AJAX calls.

Comment: @Darin - Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help. Enjoy life.

Comment: @Darin - Do you have any advise how can I distinguish between case 2 and 3 in my example? (If you prefer I can post this as a separate question!)

Comment: @Julian, no there isn't unless you send some special HTTP header along with the request. No special headers are sent with normal requests. I am not familiar with Google Chrome extensions but if you manage to send some custom header you could test for the presence of this header.